# Rotate 3D object based on normalized camera position, up, and direction

Tags: three.js, 3d, rotational-matrices

I have 3rd party tool on our website that displays 3D models. I have to built a `cube` that can control the camera of this 3D viewer.
Something like this:

[image]

This cube should rotate based on the camera of the viewer.
The camera has following functions:

```
camera.getPosition()
camera.getDirection()
camera.getUp()
```

and returned values look like this:

```
camera.getPosition: {"x":-0.14815343916416168,"y":0.10964569449424744,"z":0.0968131348490715}
camera.getDirection: {"x":0.7116152048110962,"y":-0.5266535878181458,"z":-0.46501585841178894}
camera.getUp: {"x":0.38310256600379944,"y":0.8456945419311523,"z":-0.3715282082557678}
```

How can I calculate the rotation of my cube using these values? (If possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution ended up being this:

```
// http://www.fundza.com/vectors/normalize/index.html
const normalize = ({ x, y, z }) => {
  const length = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)
  return {
    x: x / length,
    y: y / length,
    z: z / length
  }
}

// https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/cross.html
const cross = ({ x: a1, y: a2, z: a3 }, { x: b1, y: b2, z: b3 }) => ({
  x: a2 * b3 - a3 * b2,
  y: a3 * b1 - a1 * b3,
  z: a1 * b2 - a2 * b1
})

const calculateRotation = (direction, up) => {
  const right = normalize(cross(direction, up))

  const matrix = [[right.x, right.y, right.z], [direction.x, direction.y, direction.z], [up.x, up.y, up.z]]

  const angle = Math.acos((matrix[0][0] + matrix[1][1] + matrix[2][2] - 1) * 0.5)
  const axis = (() => {
    const k = Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(matrix[2][1] - matrix[1][2], 2) +
      Math.pow(matrix[0][2] - matrix[2][0], 2) +
      Math.pow(matrix[1][0] - matrix[0][1], 2)
    )

    return {
      x: (matrix[2][1] - matrix[1][2]) / k,
      y: (matrix[0][2] - matrix[2][0]) / k,
      z: (matrix[1][0] - matrix[0][1]) / k
    }
  })()

  return { angle, axis }
}
```

Then you can rotate with:

```
cubeGroup.setRotationFromAxisAngle(rotation.axis, rotation.angle)
```

And I also had to rotate my camera, which might be optional for other cases:

```
camera.rotateX(Math.PI / 2)
```